# where to look for SQL Authentication Password in Azure Portal in order to connect in Visual Studio (SQL Server Object Explorer)

Tags: sql-server, azure, visual-studio-2015

where to look for SQL Authentication Password in Azure Portal in order to connect in Visual Studio (SQL Server Object Explorer)

Answer (score 2):

you can only reset password to the sql server as shown here:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the SQL Authentication password from Azure portal or from any other source. If you have forgotten the password and have access to the portal, try resetting the password or create a new login credentials and use that.

Comment: Can i know the reason for again unmarking this as answer? just for my information